# HTTP headers printed on top of page (Microsoft Edge)

Tags: php, debugging, http-headers, microsoft-edge

The following 'code' is sometimes (random) printed on a webpage after refresh.

```
>HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>Date: Fri, 18 Mar 2016 09:05:03 GMT
>Server: Apache
>X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6-pl0-gentoo
>X-Frame-Options: DENY
>X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
>X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
>Pragma: no-cache
>Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=86
>Connection: Keep-Alive
>Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>Content-Type: text/html

>5
```

*(the last number, 5 in this case, is random, the rest is constant.*

This is what I tried to solved this annoying 'bug?':

- Removing HTML `<head>` contents
- Removing HTML `<body>` contents
- Removing AJAX (XHR) calls
- Updating Smarty (engine that parses the templates)
- PHP trim() around output to prevent unnessary spaces before or after `<doctype>` and `<html>` tags
- Killing almost all PHP code (this is to much to explain here, but since I stripped it down complety I am 99% sure it is not the serverside (PHP) code)
- Looking for PHP functions that are able to print these headers (greps for headers_list, getallheaders, apache_request_headers, etc.)
- Tried multiple pages, same results, no matter its contents.
- My customer sees the seem results on Microsoft Edge browser.
- Updated other components, like browser detection
- Added PHP ob_start();
- Validated HTML
- Made sure to clean Javascript console errors (now clean)
- Gave a go on WireShark for Windows, to look at what headers are received, but this was to difficult for me. (should I retry?)
- This problem sounds a lot like mine, but wasn't helping to fix mine: bugzilla DOT mozilla DOT org/show_bug.cgi?id=229710
- Checked other Stack Overflow questions. Could not find a matching question/solution.
- More, which I forgot :)

Notes:

- The site is server over HTTPS with a valid certificate.
- Here is the site link: https://www.10voordeleraar.nl
- Attached screenshot links below.

The funny thing is, this only happens on Microsoft Edge, sometimes. It is behaving properly on all other browsers, so do my other sites.

Regards,

Laird

Screenshots:

[Printed HTTP headers example on site top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R4SD.png)

[Printed HTTP headers example in DOM inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJilF.png)

Comment: you would need to share the site in order for folks to help. Is it returned in the raw source code of the page? When you view-source in Edge, does it show the header?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I understand,

This is the URL (URL shortener ): alturl.com/3rx4s

In the source it shows the headers as well. When I DOM-inspect the page it is shown after the <body> opening tag.

Comment: you are sending different content between chrome and edge, so it would seem as though there is an issue on the server side

Comment: Thank you Patrick, I will look into it

Comment: Update: It seems an HTTPS certificate issue. If it is, I will update this thread and mark the answer.

Comment: ANSWER: It seems like it is solved! Changed:

SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
to:
SetEnv nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown 

(I cannot accept answers yet)